# Every npm command aborted

Tags: node.js, npm

I have troubles with running `npm install` command from my ssh console.

Every time I try to install something I get this result:

[image: SSH command execution response]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Install node.js latest version again, this usually happens if correct node.js version is not installed.

Comment: I was literally doing nothing and it restarted working well. I don't know what happened. Thanks anyway

Comment: It has began doing it again... Don't know what problem could be at this point. Latest version of both Node.js and npm

Comment: I have the same problem